# subprocess.call returns 0 but command did not execute successfully

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a rather odd case that I can't seem to debug or reliably replicate.

When I run the following code for a directory with many files (~1000), there will occasionally be a few files that fail to move to the destination directory. Yet, when I check the logs, I will see that those files that failed to move still had a return code of 0, as the log files would log that they *did* move.

Initially I thought that it might have to do with the use of threading so that was removed entirely from the code but this still occurs. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
def move(origin,dest,filename):
    command = "mv " + os.path.join(origin,filename) + " " + dest
    rc = subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
    return rc

for f in files:
    # do stuff
    rc = move(origin,dest,filename)
    if rc==0:
        logging.debug('%s moved from %s to %s', f, origin, dest)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the subprocess will return a non-zero exit code upon failure? It might be that error messages are sent to stderr or stdout, but with exit code 0.

Comment: Also, I would advice against using your own subprocess calls for common filesystem operations. Are you familiar with the builtin modules `os` and `shutils`?

Comment: I thought that if you passed args to the command, it had to be as a list, not just a long string?

Comment: The man page of "mv" doesn't state anything about nonzero return codes.

Comment: @JohnGordon Not when you use `shell=True`

Comment: But it would be better to use `command = ["mv", os.path.join(origin, filename), dest]` and `shell=False`

Comment: @MichaelButscher https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1p.html#EXIT_STATUS says it returns non-zero on an error.

Comment: @Kris good point... I've tried to see the return code of the subprocess call when mv fails (when it is trying to move a non-existent file) and it _does_ return 1 instead of 0. Unfortunately I don't see a way to replicate the kind of failed mv I'm facing where the file exists but it's not moving somehow. I have a feeling it should return 1 too though. I'll take up your suggestion and try using built-in modules for now instead but since the problem happens rather randomly I can't say for sure whether that would work. I will update again if it doesn't fail the next time I have to run this code :)

Comment: One thing to add might be to be careful with special characters (like brackets and spaces) in your filepaths. If you set shell=True, you may be writing to unexpected locations. [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) might be safer.